# How to make a conditional comparing two values by their position in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
sort(stor);
    for (int i = 0; i < stor.size(); ++i){
        if (i != 0 && stor[i] == stor[i - 1]){ // is stor[i] a repeat?
            if (repCheck[repCheck.size() - 1] == stor[i]){ // do we already know about this repeat? *program crashes when reaching this line*
                ++repCount[repCount.size() - 1]; // increment the last value in repCount
            }
            else {
                repCheck.push_back(stor[i]); // store this new repeat at the end of repCheck
                repCount.push_back(1); // start a new count for repetitions at the end of repCount
            }

        }
    }
```

Program crashes upon reaching the second if statement, is there something inherently wrong about trying to compare values this way? Edited: for confusion about error messages.

Comment: And `unsigned int i` isn´t an error. If you have error messages, show the full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `if` can fail if `repCheck.size()` is 0. Is this your case ?

You will probably want to change `if (repCheck[repCheck.size() - 1] == stor[i])` into `if (repCheck.size() > 0 && repCheck[repCheck.size() - 1] == stor[i])`

Note that you can start your loop from `i = 1` and then avoid the test `i !=0` in the first `if`.

Comment: Thanks again, I will accept your answer when the time limit allows. Program works fine now. Just of curiosity, is there a reason why the if fails? It seems like it would not find a value and so it wouldn't be equal, right? Does it have to find a value for it not to crash?

Comment: @Stoddard The `if` isn´t the problem, but a `something[-1]` is. And there is a value, just not yours. Either you´ll get that value (result unpredictable because value unpredictable) or some sanity check will kill your program. If the program wasn´t killed yet, in the next line you´re modifying the same thing: again result unpredictable. Modifying some unknown variable or even CPU command is worse than just reading.